# how to keep user state login firebase Oauth android

Tags: android, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

I am beginner level coder and facing a problem :/ 
I am implementing a user Login Signup with Firebase OAuth ....

My Login Activity Code is ....

```
    public class UserLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button SignInBtn;
    EditText EmailField, PasswordField;
    TextView notReg;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;
    String UserEmail, UserPass;


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListner != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);
        Initialization(); // views initialized
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListnerSetup();


        SignInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                UserEmail = EmailField.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(UserEmail)) {
                    EmailField.setError("Enter Email.");
                }
                UserPass = PasswordField.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(UserPass)) {
                    PasswordField.setError("Enter Password");
                }
                SignIn(UserEmail, UserPass);
            }
        });

        notReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(UserLogin.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

    } //onCreate Method

    private void mAuthListnerSetup() {
        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            }
        };
    }

    private void Initialization() {
        EmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userSigninEmail);
        PasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userSigninPass);
        SignInBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SigninBtn);
        notReg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notRegUser);
    }

    private void SignIn(String email, String pass) {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(UserLogin.this, all.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And when user successfully logged in , new activity starts and I want to access user Details from next activity.... :/ 
Thanks in advance hope I will get help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
String userName = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
String emailAddress = firebaseUser.getEmail();
//and so on for the others details
```

To use data between activities you can use an `Intent` like this:

```
//FirstActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
intent.putExtra("userName", userName);
intent.putExtra("emailAddress", emailAddress);
startActivity(intent);
```

And to get the data back use this code:

```
//SecondActivity
String uid = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("uid");
String userName = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("userName");
String emailAddress = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("emailAddress");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: so is there no any other way to get Details of Logged In user from previous activity.?

Comment: Yes, there is another way, to store those details in a `SharedPreferences`. This means that you can use them across the whole app. The fist one is easier to implement if you have only a few activities.

Comment: umm can you give some guide for what should store in Prefrences and what to retrieve in next activity.... ?

Comment: or any way to save athenticate token and in next activity getting details from that authenticated token ?

Comment: ummm i thinks .... have to save email, name, etc some details and on signOut delete the prefrences and on start the app again .... have to check wheter if details are in prefrence so take to logged in activity or if prefrences empty take user to login activity. ? does my logic is true? :/

Comment: You need to store only what you need to use. As you see in the [FirebaseUser class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) there are o lot of methods, `getUid(), getDisplayName(), getEmail(), getPhoneNumber(), getPhotoUrl()` and many more. Your logic is good, you need to make a check. Give it a try and keep me posted.

Comment: answer for this question .... in the next activity that starts after loggin in , have to code same and in FirebaseUser we just have to get Instanse and User is logged in so Logged in user , we can access in next activity.

Comment: I hardly undestand you. Try first time to solve the problem with the easier solution, that i have explained above.

Comment: Yes i did above than i dont feel good with this.... so i change code for keep login

Comment: If you are using `firebase-authentication` you are always logged in, until you sign out. If you have a few actvities, the solution above is the best.

Comment: Did my answer helped you in any way?